# Matrix Multiplication: Four Loops vs Three Loops

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, nested-loops, matrix-multiplication

While my code is running without error, my resultant matrix (ie. C) is incorrect.
What C should be:[6, 20, 3, 5],[-3, 3,-2, 0],[30, 27, 5, 12],[9, 13, 8, 4].

What C currently is, based on my code:[35,45,25,15],[14,18,10,6],[-14,-18,-10,-6],[14,18,10,6]

I have a feeling this is from mismatching my loops for my resultant matrix, but I can't seem to figure out the issue.

I've also noticed that other matrix multiplication threads on this forum use 3 loops, as opposed to my 4 loops. If this is the reason for my error, could you please explain why? Shouldn't there be an iteration for the 2 separate rows and 2 separate columns?

```
const A = [  [-4,0,5],
            [-3,-1,2],
            [6,7,-2],
            [1, 1, 2]
         ];

const B = [ [1, 0, 3, 0],
            [4,5,-1, 2],
            [2, 4, 3, 1]
         ];

C = [];

for (var i =0; i< A.length; i++){
    C[i] = [];
    for (var j =0 ; j< A[j].length; j++){
        //console.log(A[i][j]);
        for (var y = 0 ; y < B[0].length ; y++){
                C[i][y] = 0;
            for (var x = 0 ; x < B.length ; x++){
                //console.log(B[x][y]+ "["+x+","+y+"]");
                //console.log(C[i][y]+ "["+i+","+y+"]"); 
                C[i][y] += A[i][j] * B[x][y];
            }
            console.log(C[i][y] + "[" + i + "," +y+"] is the resultant matrix");
        }
    }
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(C)); //to print out resultant matrix in array format
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use four loops. You need only three loops that is the problem. The no of nested loops to use for a problem are not your choice.

This problem needs only three nested loops. To multiply matrices. We multiple each element of each row of the first matrix with **corresponding** element of each column of second matrix.

Now the thing which you need to understand is that the third nested loop will generate `-4,0,5`. At this point we don't need another loop because we add them to corresponding value. Not each value is added to all.

```js
const A = [  [-4,0,5],
            [-3,-1,2],
            [6,7,-2],
            [1, 1, 2]
         ];

const B = [ [1, 0, 3, 0],
            [4,5,-1, 2],
            [2, 4, 3, 1]
         ];
const C = [];

for(let i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
  C[i] = []
  for(let j = 0; j < B[0].length; j++){
    C[i][j] = 0
    for(let k = 0; k < A[0].length; k++){    
      C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
    }  
  }
  
}
//[6, 20, 3, 5],[-3, 3,-2, 0],[30, 27, 5, 12],[9, 13, 8, 4]
console.log(C);
```

Comment: Thank you! The issue now is that the resultant matrix from your suggestion prints out 3 columns instead of four...

Comment: @SK Try refreshing I have updated the code a while ago. For me its giving correct result.

Comment: Yes it is! Thank you so much.

Comment: @SK Consider accepting the answer if you think it helped you.

Comment: Done! (I hope I did correctly though; still relatively new to Stack.)